# Error connecting Oracle on localhost: Could not get JDBC Connection?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to connect Oracle database from my web application using Eclipse.
But I got the error:org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection;

I used below code:

```
public static void initDB(){
    try {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
        ds.setUsername("mybank");
        ds.setPassword("123456");

        jdbcTemplate  = new JdbcTemplate(ds); // throw exceptiong after this line
        isConnected = true;
        initSystemPros();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot connect to DataBase");
        isConnected = false;
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
INFO: Server startup in 11564 ms 
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection) at 
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtil‌​s.java:80) at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:382) at 
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
```

I tried to use SQL Developer to create a connection using above settings and successful. 
Do you know what is wrong ?

Thanks and regards,
Tai

Comment: why is it  that you have 2 lines of code *after* the line that says : *throw exception after this line*  ? hmm, try swapping the line order ?  `isConnected = true;   initSystemPros(); jdbcTemplate  = new JdbcTemplate(ds);`

Comment: You are hiding the exception message being thrown. How full exception stack.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - you mean `sHow full exception stack.` ye?

Comment: Can you place the stacktrace as well ??

Comment: Yes that is what I meant

Comment: @coffe: if connecting is successfule, the variable isConnected = true and the function initSystemPros to create a login user

Comment: this is exception message: INFO: Server startup in 11564 ms
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:382)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that `xe` is your `Service Name`.

If the connection is successfull but you have this exception `SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection) at` 
"

you must have an incompatible version of JDBC, install the correct one:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html

Comment: :yes, xe is my service name, because I can create connection using SQL developer